# Sum dataframe column previous row and product of two columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns.

```
Date          Close  pos_chg      cash
2000-01-04  81.9375      0.0  10000.00
2000-01-05  69.7500      0.0      0.00
2000-01-06  65.5625      0.0      0.00
2000-01-07  69.5625      0.0      0.00
2000-01-10  69.1875    100.0      0.00
2000-01-11  66.7500      0.0      0.00
2000-01-12  63.5625   -200.0      0.00
2000-01-13  65.9375    200.0      0.00
2000-01-14  64.2500   -200.0      0.00
2000-01-18  64.1250      0.0      0.00
```

What I want to calculate.

```
Date          Close  pos_chg      cash
2000-01-04  81.9375      0.0  10000.00
2000-01-05  69.7500      0.0  10000.00
2000-01-06  65.5625      0.0  10000.00
2000-01-07  69.5625      0.0  10000.00
2000-01-10  69.1875    100.0   3081.25
2000-01-11  66.7500      0.0   3081.25
2000-01-12  63.5625   -200.0  15793.75
2000-01-13  65.9375    200.0   2606.25
2000-01-14  64.2500   -200.0  15456.25
2000-01-18  64.1250      0.0  15456.25
```

I thought this code would work.

```
df['cash']=df['cash'].shift(1)-(df['pos_chg']*df['Close'])
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should explain in more detail what you are trying to do and what your current approach yields compared to your expected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`pandas.Series.cumsum()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

#### Code:

```
df['delta_cash'] = (df.Close * -df.pos_chg + df.cash).cumsum()
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
    Date          Close  pos_chg      cash
    2000-01-04  81.9375      0.0  10000.00
    2000-01-05  69.7500      0.0      0.00
    2000-01-06  65.5625      0.0      0.00
    2000-01-07  69.5625      0.0      0.00
    2000-01-10  69.1875    100.0      0.00
    2000-01-11  66.7500      0.0      0.00
    2000-01-12  63.5625   -200.0      0.00
    2000-01-13  65.9375    200.0      0.00
    2000-01-14  64.2500   -200.0      0.00
    2000-01-18  64.1250      0.0      0.00"""),
                 skiprows=1)

df['delta_cash'] = (df.Close * -df.pos_chg + df.cash).cumsum()
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
         Date    Close  pos_chg     cash  delta_cash
0  2000-01-04  81.9375      0.0  10000.0    10000.00
1  2000-01-05  69.7500      0.0      0.0    10000.00
2  2000-01-06  65.5625      0.0      0.0    10000.00
3  2000-01-07  69.5625      0.0      0.0    10000.00
4  2000-01-10  69.1875    100.0      0.0     3081.25
5  2000-01-11  66.7500      0.0      0.0     3081.25
6  2000-01-12  63.5625   -200.0      0.0    15793.75
7  2000-01-13  65.9375    200.0      0.0     2606.25
8  2000-01-14  64.2500   -200.0      0.0    15456.25
9  2000-01-18  64.1250      0.0      0.0    15456.25
```